# Can't figure out how to cover a div with an image correctly for website

Tags: html, css, image

Title poorly describes the issue, sorry.
I have div's ("cards") in my website that contain a lot of content. One of the important thing's I wanted was to have an image covering the "cards", however every time I've attempted to fit them properly, they either don't change from their current setup or they take on massive size relative to the page size and not the "card" size.
I've read other threads regarding *similar* issues, but I haven't gotten anything to work yet.

[Image not fitting into Card correctly](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6HgUk.png)

```css
/* Entire div for card base + image inside it */

.card   {
   display: flex;
   flex-flow: row no-wrap;
   justify-content: space-between;
   width: 275px;
   height: 150px;
   font-size: 25px;
   padding: 20px;
   background-color: #f1f1f1;
   border-radius: 30px;
   box-shadow: 0px 0px 18px #888888;
   transition: all 0.5s ease;
}

.card:hover   {
    background-color: #daeaf5;
}

.card-image   {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    overflow: hidden
}

.card-img:hover   {
    -webkit-filter: grayscale(0%);
    filter: greyscale(0%);
}

.card-img   {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    flex-shrink: 0;
    min-width: 100%;
    min-height: 100%;
    border-radius: 30px;
    -webkit-filter: grayscale(100%);
    filter: greyscale(100%);
    -webkit-mask-image:-webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, from(rgba(0,0,0,1)), to(rgba(0,0,0,0)));
      mask-image: linear-gradient(to left, rgba(0,0,0,1), rgba(0,0,0,0));
    transition: all 0.5s ease;
}



/* ignore this stuff, it's just styling for the rest of the card */

.card-title   {
    font-size: 10px;
}

.card-content   {
    font-size: 18px;
    margin-bottom: 5px;
    white-space: nowrap;
}

.card-a   {
    color: black;
    text-decoration: none;
    border-radius: 30px;
    margin: 15px;
}

.main   {
   margin-left: 10px;
}

.flex-container   {
   display: flex;
   flex-flow: row wrap;
   justify-content: flex-start;
   align-items: flex-start;
   align-content: flex-start;
}
```

```html
/* Entire card div, yes I know my code looks like a goblin wrote it, I am a goblin. */
/*So far, this was the only way I have found to get it to work how I wanted to*/

<div class="main">
    <ul type="none">
     <div class="flex-container">

          <a class="card-a" href="###">
        <li>
          <div class="card">
            <div class="left-side">
              <div class="card-title">Make</div>
                <div class="card-content">Template</div>
              <div class="card-title">Model</div>
                <div class="card-content">Temp</div>
              <div class="card-title">Trim</div>
                <div class="card-content">Temp</div>
              <div class="card-title">Year</div>
                <div class="card-content">Temp</div>
            </div>
            <div class="right-side">
              <img class="card-img" src="https://static.turbosquid.com/Preview/001308/648/FU/_D.jpg" alt="Temporary Picture provided by Turbosquid 1308648"/>
            </div>
          </div>
        </li>
          </a>

            
     </div>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Ideally I want the image to fit snugly into the card, hence the corners on the image matching the corners on the card. I've tried to relocate the image into various places, re-sorting the div's and attempting to structure everything differently. Unfortunately, every time I've tried that, I get farther and farther away from the ideal card design. Yes I know, the code looks like chicken scratch compared to anyone else's work, please excuse my poor man's amount of experience.

Comment: Do you want the whole car image to be on the right of the text or for it to be centered in the card and therefore the text to write over a bit of it?

Comment: @AHaworth I want the image to fit the div behind it fully, and for the text to sit on top, writing over it if necessary.

Comment: Have you investigated object-fit contain? This would ensure the image was as big as possible within the contraints of the card without distortion.

Comment: I didn't try that before, however I'm not too worried about distortion, the images I will be using in the final product should fit the cards perfectly without issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```css
/* Entire div for card base + image inside it */

.card   {
   display: flex;
   flex-flow: row no-wrap;
   justify-content: space-between;
   width: 275px;
   height: 150px;
   font-size: 25px;
   padding: 20px;
   background-color: #f1f1f1;
   border-radius: 30px;
   box-shadow: 0px 0px 18px #888888;
   transition: all 0.5s ease;
   position: relative;
   overflow: hidden;
}

.card:hover   {
    background-color: #daeaf5;
}

.card-image   {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    overflow: hidden
}

.card-img:hover   {
    -webkit-filter: grayscale(0%);
    filter: greyscale(0%);
}

.card-img   {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    flex-shrink: 0;
    min-width: 100%;
    min-height: 100%;
    border-radius: 30px;
    -webkit-filter: grayscale(100%);
    filter: greyscale(100%);
    -webkit-mask-image:-webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, from(rgba(0,0,0,1)), to(rgba(0,0,0,0)));
      mask-image: linear-gradient(to left, rgba(0,0,0,1), rgba(0,0,0,0));
    transition: all 0.5s ease;
}



/* ignore this stuff, it's just styling for the rest of the card */

.card-title   {
    font-size: 10px;
}

.card-content   {
    font-size: 18px;
    margin-bottom: 5px;
    white-space: nowrap;
}

.card-a   {
    color: black;
    text-decoration: none;
    border-radius: 30px;
    margin: 15px;
}

.main   {
   margin-left: 10px;
}

.flex-container   {
   display: flex;
   flex-flow: row wrap;
   justify-content: flex-start;
   align-items: flex-start;
   align-content: flex-start;
}
.right-side{
   position: absolute;
   left: 0;
   top: 0;
   right: 0;
   bottom: 0;
}
```

```html
/* Entire card div, yes I know my code looks like a goblin wrote it, I am a goblin. */
/*So far, this was the only way I have found to get it to work how I wanted to*/

<div class="main">
    <ul type="none">
     <div class="flex-container">

          <a class="card-a" href="###">
        <li>
          <div class="card">
            <div class="left-side">
              <div class="card-title">Make</div>
                <div class="card-content">Template</div>
              <div class="card-title">Model</div>
                <div class="card-content">Temp</div>
              <div class="card-title">Trim</div>
                <div class="card-content">Temp</div>
              <div class="card-title">Year</div>
                <div class="card-content">Temp</div>
            </div>
            <div class="right-side">
              <img class="card-img" src="https://static.turbosquid.com/Preview/001308/648/FU/_D.jpg" alt="Temporary Picture provided by Turbosquid 1308648"/>
            </div>
          </div>
        </li>
          </a>

            
     </div>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: Please could you explain how this works. Thanks.

Comment: `.card   {position: relative; overflow: hidden;}` and `.right-side{ position: absolute; left: 0; top: 0; right: 0; bottom: 0;}`

Comment: Sorry, I meant in words.

Comment: Hey, Tested @AmanSharma 's solution with other cards with different images, and it worked nearly perfectly for what I wanted!
Thank you so much, I guess I was over-complicating the issue by looking at the similar threads and seeing people use JS and ect.

Comment: @volt-kent don't forget to upvote! :-)

Comment: @AmanSharma I hope you'll accept a imaginary upvote from me! Unfortunately, I can't upvote the literal answer because I don't meet stack-overflow's requirements yet.

Comment: @volt-kent :-) ...

Answer (score 0):

use the CSS background-image property
then play with its properties till you get what you want I.E:

```
<div id="card_image">
  <h1>hello World</h1>
  <p>this Section Has a background image</p>
</div>

<style>
  #card_image {
   background-image:url("https://static.turbosquid.com/Preview/001308/648/FU/_D.jpg");
background-size:25%;
backgroun-position:top right;
}
</style>
play with this
```

Comment: This was actually one of the first things that I tried, and it wouldn't fit the div space/link space correctly no matter how I fiddled with it. Good suggestion nonetheless, but wouldn't work for my project.